# Serving a page with Python web.py, how can I get it to reload and dynamically change the page after a timeout?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web.py

I currently have an extremely basic Python webapp.  I am utilizing it to do some base tests against a SmartTV browser that doesn't support javascript even remotely well.

I need to be able to point the TV browser to the URL for my webapp, have it load a page containing a div with just a gif contained within, then say every 10 seconds, reload the page, switching to a different gif.  It can be just two gifs that switch back and forth, but I need to figure out how to make this happen without Javascript reloading the page.  Or perhaps with the very most basic javascript in the whole wide world to reload the page, but I've tried several js actions and met with various types of poor handling, resulting in unexpected results that, while interesting, did not test what I've been tasked with testing.

Here's my current code from app.py:

```
import web
import time

urls = (
  '/', 'Index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/')

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
    currentGif = 'http://10.111.0.221/onegif/cosmicShip.gif'
    return render.index(currentGif = currentGif)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The template that's calling is a simple div as described above, passing the URL to put up the gif as the background image.  What I'd like to do is find some way to basically just add a sleep(10) after that return, switch currentGif to the second gif file, and return the page again.

I know doing it that way isn't reality, but it's the most simple way I can think to explain what I want.  I just need to load the page ones, and have it loop between two pages until I manually exit, and I don't believe JavaScript is a viable option for this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it can be done with out javascript. Your client will need to make another GET request to your server to redirect. Once your server sends the page the connection is closed. You can try to poll the client but how would you handle that if you limited access to the client.

Comment: Javascript is the solution. Try adding a route in the urls tuple, and add a new handler that would return just the image path, alternating from one to another. Then make an asynchronous call to your new route and update the div background image with the new path every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use javascript to refresh in that amount of time and passing by GET params the ID of the page an then you at the python controller call the other page.

Javascript need it for the client part. Or reload or call an ajax function all the time with a sleep.

Python: Controller saving the state and respond with the corrent status.

Comment: Thanks for the folks that commented/answered.  The downside is that getting javascript to work properly (or at all) on some of these so called Smart TV's is challenging at best, but we're continuing to work on things going that way and have had some limited luck with a couple models.  Appreciate the information that was provided here.